# Ubuntu not recognizing my Samsung pcie nvme drive

Tags: boot, system-installation, 22.04, raid

I just bought a Dell Inspiron 14 7430 laptop with the hopes of installing Ubuntu on it using a hard drive connected via USB. However, whenever I try to install the only drive that Ubuntu recognizes is the one that my computer is booting from. I have spent hours looking at guides and other questions about this same issue, but none of the solutions provided in those have been of any help to me. Many answers have said to switch the SATA controller from RAID to AHCI, but my BIOS does not have any option for that. Additionally, I looked at the info on my ssd in the BIOS and its status is "Non-RAID."

So far I have tried:

- Disabling secure boot
- Disabling fast boot
- Adding "nvme_load=YES" as a boot option

My system is running a 13th Gen Intel I7-1355U processor.
The drive I am trying to install Ubuntu on is a Samsung PCIe NVMe PM9B1
I am trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Comment: My 11th Gen Intel Dell just worked with 22.04. Both an internal install & external to Samsung NVMe. I did have to turn off bitlocker & fast start up in Windows. I made sure UEFI firmware was latest version & updated SSD firmware. Since new system, you may need 23.04 to have latest kernel & drivers. You do need to partition in advance. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 &  https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/tools/ Version info: `udisksctl status`